# Android WebView does not work with Wordpress menu based on Anchor Link (Jump Link)

Tags: android, wordpress, webview, anchor

I developing simple app which has to display website in a webview. Webside is build in word press and button which suppose open the menu does not work (it does work in normal browser).

Container of the menu:

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation" class="mm-menu mm-horizontal mm-current mm-opened"> ..</nav>
```

Link to the menu:

```
<a href="#access" id="menu-btn" class="active"></a>
```

When i click on the link from regular browser menu slight from right but url is not affected i mean it is stil SomeDomain.com instead of SomeDomain.com/#access.

Important info:

-I already try to reload link in `onPageFinished` (with and without adding #access at the end)

-My webView is NOT in the ScrollView

-i have set `webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

I'm loading my web like: 
    mainWebView.loadUrl(url);

Do you have any ideas how to fix that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figure that out, problem was that my webview was not fully support html5:

```
mWebView.setFocusable(true);
mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Comment: The only one here necessary is `myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`. Setting Webview elements focusable does nothing to expand the menu. PluginsEnabled doesn't exist, Caching requires a database which is also irrelevant, and enabling Dom Storage here is also unrelated .

Comment: setDomStorageEnabled is doing the trick for me. Great solution.

Comment: Just a heads up setCacheMode has been deprecated.Quoting from developer.android :"The Application Cache API is deprecated and this method will become a no-op on all Android versions once support is removed in Chromium. Consider using Service Workers instead. See https://web.dev/appcache-removal/ for more information."

Answer (score 1):

**don't miss this one**

```
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

**this one work for me..**